# Gin Gonic - Literal colon inside the URL

Tags: api, rest, go

I'm creating some REST API with Gin Gonic in go.
I have to expose this endpoint with this URL:
 `/api/v1/action::request::export`
I'm using gin gonic to create the routes and I got this error "only one wildcard per path segment is allowed" because the colon ":" is used to map a parameters in the URL.

There is a way to escape the ":" character and use it into the URL?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not use `/api/v1/action/:request/:export`

Comment: @rosmak it's not depending from me but from a framework that we're using. it's requesting the url composed in this way

Comment: i think you can use /api/v1/:action and in code get `c.Param("action ")` and parse with your format! in path after ( / ) you can only use one ( : ) [link](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/205#issuecomment-296155497)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [F.S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15523781/f-s) mentioned in comment, you could use just one pathParam `action`
and then in code handle parsing as needed.

Here is an example that would work for you:

```golang
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/api/v1/:action", func(c *gin.Context) {
        params, ok := c.Params.Get("action")
        if !ok {
            // handle error
        }

        eachParam := strings.SplitN(params, ":", 3)
        request, export := eachParam[1], eachParam[2] // your actual params divided by ":"

        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "good",
        })
    })
    r.Run()
}
```

But of course, this approach have its own caveats, you have to handle exceptions and edge cases yourself.